# Using WFS Vector layers in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, overlay

I have some code in loop:

```
var vector =   new ol.layer.Vector({
                                title: name,
                                style: styleFunction
                            });
                             function getFeatures(geoJson) {
                                // If response is valid
                                var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON({
                                    featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
                                });
                                vector.setSource(
                                        new ol.source.Vector({
                                            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                                            features: format.readFeatures(geoJson),

                                        }));
                            }

                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: urlAjax,
                                dataType: 'jsonp',
                                jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
                                success:getFeatures
                            });

                            overlays.push(vector)
```

After push vector to overlay array I add that array of vectors to map:

```
 var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Base maps',
                layers: basemaps
            }),
            new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Overlays',
                layers: overlays
            })

        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([31.4, 48.9]),
            zoom: 6
        })
    });
```

And create switcher controls... And all vectors are reset sources last layer and only last layer visible in map, others don`t work...why?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I had problem because I used ajax. Requests was asynchronized and source created asynchronized too... now I use this code to get sources:

```
 var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
                        title: bean.name,
                        style: styleFunction,
                        source:new ol.source.Vector({
                                format:new ol.format.GeoJSON({
                                    featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"}),
                                url:bean.urlAjax
                        })
```